# How to create SOAP client with spring application

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, soap, jsf-2, wsdl

I need to create a client with WSDL. I have a Java web application with JSF, Spring and JPA. In this application I need to create a form and send the info to the SOAP web service. This service should return another object with status.

Please, any idea I will be grateful

regards

sorry by my english

Comment: The web service you are trying to call, is it complicated or simple?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have generated classes from the WSDL needed for you client. In Spring it is very simple by using [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). For e.g.:

```
<jaxws:client id="yourService"
              serviceClass="com.something.YourService"
              address="the URL of web service"
              username="username"
              password="password"/>
```

And in your class where you need to call this web service just autowire it:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("yourService")
private YourService service;
```

Take a look at the example: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Comment: how to i define header message? i get this error: Caused By: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Technical: OSB Assign action failed updating variable "bodyEntradaBS000112": com.bea.wli.common.xquery.XQueryException: Error parsing XML: {err}FORG0005: expected exactly one item, got 0 items